# Self populate in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, parent-child, populate

I am using mongoose and nodejs have  schema like this:

```
var category = new Schema({
      name: String,
      parent: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'category', default: null }]
    });
```

and on category collection i have 2 document like this
document 1:

```
{
  "_id" : "d3d4c44r43ce4366f563fg",
  "name" : "document 1",
  "parent" : null
}
```

document 2 :

```
{
  "_id" : "d3d4c65ygyb779676768p54",
  "name" : "document 1",
  "parent" : "d3d4c44r43ce4366f563fg"
}
```

How can i get all children from document 1 using populate in mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

**If you know which parent you want, you can do this:**

Find the child with the required parent id(`parent_id`) and `populate` using `populate('parent')`

```
//Assuming you know the parent id to populate (parent_id)
category.find({parent : parent_id}).populate('parent').exec(function(err,docs){...});
```

**EDIT : CHILD OF ALL DOCUMENT WHOSE PARENT ARE NULL**

First, find all the documents whose `parent` is `null`. and for each of those, `populate` the collection using above method.

```
category.find({parent:null},function(err,results)
{
    if(!err)
    {
        //for each parent, populate their children.
        results.forEach(result,index,array)
        {
            //result._id is the parent id, use this to retrieve its child
            category.find({parent : result._id}).populate('parent').exec(function(err,docs)
            {
                //use these docs however you want to use.
                //For every parent different `docs` array will be there.
            });
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: I want to get all children of all category have parent field is null